# iPhone Application Loader

Tags: iphone

I've downloaded the iPhone Application Loader and installed it, installation was successful, but no icon appears in my Utilities folder as expected.

Where is the Application Loader installed ?

Regards,
Stephen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind, just found it buried in developer/Applications/Utilities/